# Nextjs api and authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, next.js, vercel

I'm in the process of building an application for stripe payments. This application generates a form that passes the data to the Stripe api via nextjs api. I just need to build in some basic authentication so only those submitting their payments via my form have access to the api. How would I go about adding some basic auth to my api without requiring users to login? Would I do this via env variable? I'm fairly new to the nextjs/vercel world and come from the python/django/react realm, so maybe my thoughts on this are backwards... I'm planning on hosting the api on vercel and the react form on a php site. So the react form will essentially push data to the vercel app api. 
(The reason I'm not building the api in php is because I don't know php and because I'm attempting to build something with as little footprint in the current php site as possible.) Any help or guidance on this would be much appreciated!

**My pages/api/customers.js file**

```
import Stripe from 'stripe'

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.SECRET_KEY)

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { email, name, address, phone, source } = req.body

      // Check for customer
      const customerExist = await stripe.customers.list(
        {
          email: email,
          limit: 0
        })
      // console.log('customerExist', customerExist.data[0])
      if (customerExist.data.length < 1) {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
          email,
          name,
          address,
          phone,
          source
        })
        res.status(200).send(customer.id)
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(customerExist.data[0].id)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message })
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST')
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed')
  }
}
```

Part of my checkout form

```
  // Function to check/create a user account via api
  const checkUserAccount = async (billingDetails, source) => {
    try {
      const customer = await axios.post('/api/customers', {
        email: billingDetails.email,
        name: billingDetails.name,
        phone: billingDetails.phone,
        address: billingDetails.address,
        source: source
      })
      return customer.data
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:

Alright, so I added a "TOKEN" to my `.env` file and now require my api to receive that specific token.

I added this to my checkout form:

```
...
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
...
```

and then added this to the api:

`if (req.method === 'POST' && req.headers.authorization === process.env.AUTH_TOKEN)...`

Since I'm not using a login/logout system, I'm hoping this is enough. Thoughts or feedback are more than welcome.

Comment: Hi there, for what it's worth the Stripe portion of your integration looks good - no glaring issues. Authenticating requests without having users login doesn't strike me as a very plausible goal. The most common approaches to authenticating requests are: OAuth, HTTP Basic Auth, and API keys (e.g., through a header). All of these approaches require _some_ form of login, because you need to identify the user. That is, if you don't identify a user (have them login) then every visitor is treated the same and is "authorized".

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm not worried so much about treating everyone as "authorized" users. My concern was related to people using my api outside of the form to test credit cards.

Comment: Also @ttmarek, your tutorial on reactjs and stripe was fantastic! What I have now is built off of that. So thank you! I can't explain to you how much that single video helped propel what I'm currently building. Thanks again!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1oLdAPyuok&list=PLy1nL-pvL2M6IYfRCmhOPcyC70zJqFoCs&index=4&t=0s

Comment: Awe, thank you! I appreciate that. Great point on card testing. For that I would recommend going over: https://stripe.com/docs/card-testing. A good first step would be adding a captcha, in which case you'd pass the token generated by the token to you backend to verify the response as shown here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: I'll check out those links and look into adding a captcha. Thank you so much for sharing that info!